# Mongoose unable to connect with Mongo Standalone replicaSet

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

Detail about the issue.

I have converted my MongoDB instance to a standalone ReplicaSet using the following config.

```
systemLog:  
  destination: file   
  path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log  
  logAppend: true  
storage:  
  dbPath: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb  
net:  
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  
replication:  
  replSetName: "rs0"  
security:  
    authorization: "enabled"  
    keyFile: /Users/username/mongodb.key
```

Using the following Mongo URI to connect to my MongoDB instance

**"mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/dbName?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0"**

using the URI I can connect to my MongoDB through Studio3T but when I use this URI in my Node app through Mongoose it never connects, nor gives any error.

---

Following are the Screenshots for rs.status() output displaying details of member
[member data from rs.status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5JnV.png)

---

Additional details.
NodeJs version: v14.19.1
Mongoose version: 6.3.2
MongoDB version: 5.0.7

Comment: "Standalone replicaSet" is a contradiction. Either you have a **Standalone** MongoDB or a **ReplicaSet** (or as third option a **Sharded Cluster**) - you cannot have both at the same time. What is the purpose of a replica set with just one member?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Did you [initiate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/) the replica set?

Comment: I have made a Standalone replicaset to use monstache, and yes I did initiate the replica set.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Transactions do not work unless you are using a replica set, even if it's just one member. Trying to start a transaction with a standalone server will produce the error `MongoServerError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos`.

Comment: Please show us the code in Node. If the application is just hanging without any error, then it is either a closed firewall (which cannot be the case on localhost) or a error in your code.